# Change kendo grid Datasource use JS

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have Kendo grid and I set data source use this

```
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                .Ajax()
                                .PageSize(20)

                                .Read(read => read.Action("GetWorker", "Worker"))
```

I have button on my page and I want change datasource when I press this button(use java script). I want do somwthing like this

```
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                .Ajax()
                                .PageSize(20)

                                .Read(read => read.Action("GetDisabled", "Worker"))
```

I try do like this

```
var grid = $("grid").data("kenodGrid");
            grid.dataSource().read()
```

but I don't know what to do after grid.dataSource(). how can I change data source?
Thnaks and hope for you help

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I think you should first create a new DataSource (see https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/datasource/remote-data-binding for remote data)

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: [
        { name: "John Doe", age: 33 }
    ]
});
```

And then append it to the grid by using the setDataSource method (https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/methods/setdatasource)

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
grid.setDataSource(dataSource);
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you want to change the action for your read then you can just do that.
According to [this question](https://www.telerik.com/forums/change-datasource-url-on-grid) you could just set the dataSource Read url and refresh your grid data with something like that:

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
grid.dataSource.transport.options.read.url = "newUrlPath";
grid.dataSource.read();
grid.refresh();
```

If you don't actually want to change your dataSource but your data and possibly get your list of items from some ajax request as json then I will write down the way I do it as an example in case someone wants it.

```
var jsonData = ... // From some ajax response
var newKendoDatasource = newKendoDS(jsonData);
$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data(newKendoDatasource._data);
```

The function is like the above pretty much

```
function newKendoDS(ndata) {
    var datasource = new kendo.data.DataSource({ data: ndata });
    datasource.read(); // In order to refresh
    return datasource;
}
```